# How to access session from DS.RESTAdapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, devise

I am building an Ember-CLI application. I use ember-cli-simple-auth-devise. I have successfully authenticated from back-end and got API token. In order to send the token in each request header I am trying the following code as described here http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: "http://localhost:3000",
  namespace: "api/v1",
  headers: function() {
    return {"X-Access-Token": this.get("session.user_token")};
  }.property("session.user_token")
});
```

But this does not work. I inspected

```
this.get("session.user_token")
```

Which results undefined. So the session is not accessible ins DS.RESTAdapter. How to make the session helper available for DS.RESTAdapter?

Comment: I am having the same issue but I'm not using devise. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that at all. Simply configure the [Devise authorizer](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise#the-authorizer) which will inject the token header into every request automatically:

```
//config/environment.js
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
}
```

Comment: I will give you 1000 up votes for you if stackoverflow allows me. Thank you.